Trying to modify a kernel variable by eBPF, is it possible?
I am trying to modify a kernel variable during runtime in kernel version 5.14. Is this feasible? Are there any specific methods such as using kfuncs or modifying syscalls that I could use to achieve this? Could you also provide some detailed examples or relevant links?
I try to use kfuncs, and checked BPF.support_kfunc() is True. When including #include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>, I receive an error indicating that the file cannot be found. After including it using the absolute path, I get the error: fatal error: 'bpf_helper_defs.h' file not found (the bpf/bpf_helpers.h includes this file via a relative path). After copying bpf_helper_defs.h to the corresponding directory, I encounter a conflict with the definition in /virtual/include/bcc/helpers.h.
And I am trying to implement my own kfunc in the Linux 5.14 kernel. I have added a function and its corresponding prototype in helpers.c, but I am unable to recognize this symbol in the BCC test.py script.
BPF_CALL_1(bpf_update_variable, u32 *, new_value){
    if(new_value)
        my_dummy = * new_value;
    return 0;
}

const struct bpf_func_proto bpf_update_variable_proto = {
    .func       = bpf_update_variable, 
    .gpl_only   = false,
    .ret_type   = RET_INTEGER,
    .arg1_type  = ARG_PTR_TO_INT,
};


How could such a kfunc ever be safe for the general case? And if you don't care about upstreaming it, then why limit yourself to eBPF? Linux kernel modules would likely allow you to implement what you want.
